# Order Statistics: How to calculate expected value of a function involving first and second order statistics

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, order-statistics, integral

I am currently stuck with a challenging problem. I have n values drawn i.i.d.  from a distribution F(x).
Let $v_1$ be the nth order statistic (highest value) and let $v_2$ be the n-1 order statistic (second highest value).
Then, what is the expected value of a function of them:

1. What is the expected value of $\frac{v_1 - v_2}{v_1}$ : $$E[\frac{v_1 - v_2}{v_1}]$$
2. What is the the expected value of $\frac{v_1 - v_2}{v_1} * \frac{v_2}{2}$
   $$\frac{v_1 - v_2}{v_1} * \frac{v_2}{2}$$
   I would highly appreciate it if you could give me some direction or explain how to calculate it.

Comment: You have to compute the integrals (or sums, depending on the type of distribution).  If you have a particular $F$ in mind, we could potentially go much further towards an answer.

Comment: @StephanKolassa unfortunatelly, I made a spelling error and it is not possible to cancel $v_2$

Comment: @whuber I wanted to solve the issue in general, but what if we assume that $F(x) = x, \; x\in [0,1]$, so a uniform distribution

Comment: By “second order statistic” do you mean the second-lowest of $n$ iid observations from $X$? If so the usual notation is $X_{(2)}$. Or if you mean the second-highest, then $X_{(n-1)}$.

Comment: @Matt It makes no difference, because upon considering $-X$ the order statistics are reversed.

Comment: @MattF. My apologies, I was referring to the highest and second-highest value, so $X_{n}, X_{n-1}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u$ be the second-highest order statistic, and $v$ the highest order statistic.

Then we can write the joint pdf for $u$ and $v$ as the $i=n-1$, $j=n$ case of the theorem 5.4.6 [here](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture37.pdf),
$$n(n-1)F(u)^{n-2}f(u)f(v)$$

So we calculate the expectations by integrating this expression times $(v-u)/v$ or $(u/2)(v-u)/v$, integrating over  the region with $u<v$.

For the uniform distribution these integrals give $1/n$ and $(n-1)/2(n+1)^2$.

Comment: +1. But it may be worth noting this doesn't work for discrete distributions, where the possibility of ties makes the formulas more complicated.

Comment: @whuber & Matt F. thank you very much!

Comment: Here's the [most recent archive.org link for the pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20191005171805/http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture37.pdf), which is a set of lecture notes on order statistics by Prof. Hung Chen, National Taiwan University. This may be useful if the URL goes dead ([link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) is a problem on our site, sadly!)

Comment: @Silverfish, if the link goes dead, Wikipedia also has the formula, with some explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution

Comment: When you say "the uniform distribution", I think you mean one with $0$ as the lower end of the support

Comment: @Henry, yes, and even more specifically the distribution on $[0,1]$ as mentioned in one of the OP’s comments on the question

Comment: @MattF. Thank you, I think it's best to edit that into the question rather than leave it as a comment - comments are potentially transitory and not all readers will see them, particularly in longer comment threads